# Why does the interface twitch when changing the state variable?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Content view:

```
@State var login: String = ""
@State var password: String = ""
@State var isLoginTextViewActive = false
@State var isPasswordTextViewActive = false

    VStack {
        TextField("Login", text: $login, onEditingChanged: { isEditing in
            print(isEditing)
            self.isLoginTextViewActive = isEditing
            }
        )
        TextField("Password", text: $password)
        HorizontalLine(color: isLoginTextViewActive ? Color.yellow : Color.black, height: CGFloat(1))
        }.frame(width: CGFloat(200), alignment: .center)
```

Line code:

```
struct HorizontalLineShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {

        let fill = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height)
        var path = Path()
        path.addRoundedRect(in: fill, cornerSize: CGSize(width: 2, height: 2))

        return path
    }
}

struct HorizontalLine: View {
    private var color: Color? = nil
    private var height: CGFloat = 1.0

    init(color: Color, height: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
    }

    var body: some View {
        HorizontalLineShape().fill(self.color!).frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: height, maxHeight: height)
    }
}
```

When you change the focus between "TextView", they begin to twitch as if due to a change in height. I checked, every time the line initializer is called, but what to do with it I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because there is a bug with the font size in textfields currently. If you set your font size manually for example 20, it will work like you want.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("Login", text: $login, onEditingChanged: { isEditing in
            print(isEditing)
            self.isLoginTextViewActive = isEditing
        })
        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .medium, design: .default)) // SET SIZE

        TextField("Password", text: $password)
            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .medium, design: .default)) // SET SIZE

        Rectangle()
            .frame(height: 1)
            .foregroundColor(isLoginTextViewActive ? Color.yellow : Color.black)
    }.frame(width: CGFloat(200), alignment: .center)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But if I set 16 px, twitch start again. If 20 all normal. Its bug not only setting size...

Comment: @AleksandrMaybach Iknow, it's not nice but you can use this for temporary solution.